# .git folders are symbolic links to folders inside .repo

Tags: git, repo

I have cloned trusty code as follows:

```
mkdir trusty; cd trusty
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/trusty/manifest -b master
repo sync -c
```

Then, I see that git log is unexpectedly empty.

One observation is that, in each of the git projects of this repo, the .git folders are symbolic links like below, instead of being folders:

```
cd $(Repo_root)/external/linux
ls 
.git -> ../../.repo/projects/external/linux.git/
```

What could have caused this ?

Comment: Added the `repo` tag since this question is not really about Git, but rather about Android's Source Control Tools and its `repo` command.

Comment: Note that this is how `repo` is supposed to work. There may be options to change that (I don't use `repo`, though I vaguely recall looking at it briefly about a decade ago for some previous job; I imagine it's evolved rather a lot since then) but as a workaround you can run `git -C .git log` for instance.